# Inward regular, not outward regular measure which is not locally finite

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I want to find a measure, which is not locally finite, not outer regular but inner regular.

Would the following example be correct?

$\mu$ on the measure space $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ defined by:
$$\mu(A) = \int_{A\setminus \{0\}} \frac{1}{|x|} \, dx + \delta_0(A)\, .$$

Comment: Yes, it would, nice idea. But you should still verify that your desired properties are satisfied.